# Android App with HTML/CSS/jQuery. [How] Can it be done?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I know this has been asked before (did not find a straight forward answer) but can I (Or how can I) create and Android App using CSS/HTML/Jquery ?

I will not need to hook into native functions, such as the accelerometer, camera, or even the Toast Messages...I only need to create an app to show a list of names and some details when name is selected, therefore I don't know if it's worth learning to make my life more complicated for something like this.

PS: I need the app to work offline, otherwise I would have just made it with jQuery Mobile and uploaded it on a server.

### UPDATE AFTER GETTING DOWNVOTED

Ok, so I get downvotes for this question, probably because it's been asked before, or maybe not, since he/she didn't take the time to write a reason...
Anyway, my point is: I did googled it and searched, but at this moment there are a lot of ads of websites and web apps that will help you do this **BUT** are they reliable, safe..do they really do the trick or it comes with bugs? That is why I asked the question, to see who used what and what was their experience with it. So yeah, you can downvote me for not trusting every ad and not taking the time to try out everything out there!

Comment: 1 DownVote - 0 Reasons...Yeah, thanks, this sure helps me improve and get less on your nerves...Geesh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools to develop cross-platform apps. I used it to develop too. It is quite good but it only has one major issue: you can't use php. It also enables you to do on-device testing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will look into it, +1 for you ;)

Comment: Well, just installed XDK and I can work with the fact that I won't be able to use php with it, thanks ;) I'll be up all night wondering around through it. I will accept the answer :)

Comment: I just have been 3 down votes because the question same ur ques : "How to make iOS app with HTML?" :)